# unused variable warning in if/else

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

I'm trying to compose the variable requestURL. However I want ithe value to be different, depending on the value of request methodName. When I use the code below however, I get an error stating

> "Warning": unused variable 'requestURL'". What am I doing wrong here?

```
if ([[request methodName] isEqualToString:@"getTargets"]) {
    NSString *TMPrequestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
    NSString *trailingSlash = @"/";
    NSString *requestUrl = [TMPrequestUrl stringByAppendingString:trailingSlash];
}
else{
    NSString *requestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
}
```

Comment: A variable declaration only lasts as far as the enclosing `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you like to keep the requestUrl after your if/else statement:

```
NSString *requestUrl = nil;
if ([[request methodName] isEqualToString:@"getTargets"]) {
    NSString *TMPrequestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
    NSString *trailingSlash = @"/";
    requestUrl = [TMPrequestUrl stringByAppendingString:trailingSlash];
}
else{
    requestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong - it just warns you that you are not using the requestURL variable.

Probably you wanted to do something like that:

```
NSString *requestUrl = nil;
if ([[request methodName] isEqualToString:@"getTargets"]) {
    NSString *TMPrequestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
    NSString *trailingSlash = @"/";
    requestUrl = [TMPrequestUrl stringByAppendingString:trailingSlash];
}
else{
    requestUrl = [addressSSL stringByAppendingString:[request methodName]];
}

//use requestUrl here
// [self someMethod:requestUrl]
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler don't know that `NSString *requestUrl` declured inside the `if`,

Hence you should declare the requestUrl string outside the scope of the `if` statement with empty string, and append the required value inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when either the `if` or the `else` block is executed. `requestUrl` goes of scope, having never been used.

What you probably want to do is declare `requestUrl` *before* the `if` statement and then assign in the `if/else`.